# How To Change The Background Color of a DIV When User Hovers Over HREF Contained Within?

Tags: html, background-color, onmouseover

I have a menubar containing several menu items.

[image: menubar with menu items]

The menubar is a *div* containing the menu items (which are also *divs*) and inside of each menu item i have an *href*.

Here is the HTML:

```
<style>
.menubar-style {
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: white; 
    height: 20px; 
    text-align:center;
}
.menuitem-style {
    float: left; 
    width: 10%; 
    border-right: thin; 
    border-right-style:solid;
}
</style>
...
...
<div class="menubar-style">
    <div class="menuitem-style"><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
    <div class="menuitem-style"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
    <div class="menuitem-style"><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is change the background color of the menu item (the *div*, not just the *href*) when the cursor is over top of the link.

How can I capture the *mouseover* event from the link and use that to paint the background color of the entire menu item?

Better yet, is there a way to check if the mouse is over the entire menu item (the *div* not just the link)? That would be a better option because the menu item would change color with the mouse anywhere over the box not just the link.

Thanks in advanced!

Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply add `:hover` selector to any predefined style to only apply it while the mouse is hovering over that particular object

```
.menuitem-style:hover {
    background-color: red;   // only changes to red if the mouse is hovering.
}
```

Comment: Cool! I notice, however, that you are changing the border-right-style and not the background color? Or is that what is actually happening? I guess I could try it out and see. :)

Comment: Yeah and disregard my comment above. I just need to add  _background-color_ to the hover.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use some javascript or jQuery to do this. It would be easier to just change the color of the div as you mouse over the div, though.

Add this in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You should add a class to your `<a>` tag, let's call this class `menu-link`. So instead of `<a href="#">Link 1</a>` you would have `<a href="#" class="menu-link">Link 1</a>`.

Now, you can add the following jQuery code to your `<head>`:

```
<script>
     $('a.menu-link').hover(function()
     {
         $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
     }, function()
     {
         $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'white');
     }
</script>
```

This jQuery code will change the background color of the parent of the `<a>` tag, which in this case is your `<div>` tag.

Comment: jQuery for handling just the hover event??

Comment: He wanted to change the div when hovering over the a tag on the inside. Of course, it's probably easier/better to just change the div when hovering over the div, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Your solution is correct and to the question. What i meant was that including jQuery is an overkill for such a small requirement.

Comment: The nice thing is that you can easily adapt this code to use .animate() with the jQuery color plugin to have a smoother transition.